# Status of the dense-set version of the Halpern–Läuchli theorem

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

The Halpern–Läuchli theorem theorem of dimension $d\in \omega+1$ is the following strong Ramsey theoretic statement:

> Given $k\in \omega$ and $d$ perfect finitely branching subtrees $T_i, i<d$ of
>   $\omega^{<\omega}$, given any coloring $f: \Pi_{i<d} T_i\to k$, there exists strongly embedded subtrees $T_i'\subset T_i$ and $A\in[\omega]^{\aleph_0}$ is the common level set shared by $T_i'$ such that $f\restriction \Pi_{i<d}T'_i[A]$ is constant.

Some definitions:

- $T'\subset T$ is a strongly embedded subtree if $T'$ is a perfect subtree and there exists an infinite level set $A_{T'}$ such that $\sigma\in Splitting(T')\rightarrow height(\sigma)\in A_{T'}$ and for any $\sigma\in T', height(\sigma)\in A$, for each $\tau\in Successor_T(\sigma)$, there exists a $\tau'\in T'$ such that $\tau'\succ\tau$. **Think about a subtree that only branches at some designated levels and also the branching pattern coincides with the original tree**

Laver proved the weaker statement for dimension $\omega$, in the sense that it is not required that these trees are strongly embedded subtrees, they are only required to be perfect subtrees with some common level set $A$.
At the end of the paper, he asked if the dense-set version of the theorem in the infinite dimension is also true (it implies that strong subtree version of the theorem).

Earlier today I found this paper, https://www.jstor.org/stable/43666463?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents,
HALPERN-LÄUCHLY THEOREM ON THE PRODUCT OF INFINITELY MANY TREES IN THE VERSION OF STRONGLY EMBEDDED TREES
Goran Ramović
Publikacije Elektrotehničkog fakulteta. Serija Matematika
No. 7 (1996), pp. 18-24

For some reason I have no access to it so I don't know if the problem has been resolved there. Does anyone have access to the paper or know if the question has been answered there? It would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: ** The dense-set version can be found: http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-29/3/385.full.pdf+html (this is the last question Laver asked). 
Also I got hold of the paper from a friend and after a quick look it seems that the strong subtree version of the theorem was proved there. Still it would be interesting to know the status of the question Laver asked in the end (which implies strong subtree version immediately).

Comment: Is this the dense set version that you are referring to? https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2671

Comment: No. Let me add a link explaining this.